# Are randomly created Queen's Quadrille and Hippodrome puzzles always solvable?

Tags: chess-variants, puzzles

I found two chess puzzles on [chessvariants.com](https://www.chessvariants.com), [Queens's Quadrille](https://www.chessvariants.com/solitaire.dir/quadrille.html) and [Hippodrome](https://www.chessvariants.com/solitaire.dir/hippodrome.html).

I'm thinking of creating **random** Queen's Quadrille and Hippodrome puzzles with a computer program.

My question is can I always be sure that a randomly generated Queen's Quadrille or Hippodrome puzzle is solvable?

Should I additionally check if it is solvable after generating a random puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking whether all Queen's Quadrille and Hippodrome problems are solvable? They are not. There is a discussion on the Hippodrome page which you link to. Here is an example of a starting position which is valid both for Queen's Quadrille and for Hippodrome, and where no moves are available:

```
        5bbQ/4BRrB/4krRK/4NNnn/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
```

Perhaps you could consider a version of Hippodrome where the player gets to choose which of the 12 non-knight pieces is removed. Then it seems more plausible that all positions are solvable.